# Using result of prepared statement as temp table in query

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

If I have the output of a prepared statement; how do I use it as the source of my query?

```
CALL `myProcedure`;

PREPARE stmnt FROM @allSQL;

EXECUTE stmnt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmnt;
```

So, I get an output from the `EXECUTE stmnt;` (let's call it `tmp`) and I would like to run a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM (EXECUTE stmnt) AS tmp WHERE this = that;
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You need to prepare the whole query, not the subquery.

Comment: @Barmar that is my fear :(

Comment: @matthias - why do you not prepare the hole statement like : **CALL `myProcedure`;
SET @allSQL := CONCAT ('SELECT * FROM (',@allSQL,') AS tmp WHERE this = that');
PREPARE stmnt FROM @allSQL;
EXECUTE stmnt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmnt;**

Comment: @BerndBuffen thanks, it seems barmar had the same idea.

Comment: @matthias - yes, but he use a tmp table

Comment: @berndbuffen oh I see! sorry I misread. Thanks, I'll try this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepare a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement that contains the result of the query:

```
SET @createSQL = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS ', @allSQL);
PREPARE stmt FROM @createSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE this = that;
```

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with that prepare statement ?  it causes and error.

Comment: For some reason you can't create directly from a function call, I had to assign it to a variable first.

Comment: Thank you for your help.